# "TypeError: x is not a function" even when code works

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the above error in a function in my project and have simplified the code down to the below. The console is successfully logging the correct result but then an overlay and error still show up.

Is there any way to stop this from happening? It seems odd to throw an error when it still ran correctly.

```
func1 = (x,y) => {
  let result=(x+y)
  console.log(result)
}

func2 = x => {
  x()   // <= TypeError pointing to this not being a function
}


func2(func1(1,4)) // returns 5 but still getting TypeError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func2` accepts a *function* as a parameter, but you're passing it `func1(1,4)` as a parameter, which evaluates to `undefined` (since `func1` doesn't return anything).

Pass a function which *invokes* `func` with the desired parameters, if that's what you want to do:

```js
const func1 = (x, y) => {
  const result = x + y;
  console.log(result);
}

const func2 = x => {
  x();
};


func2(() => func1(1, 4));
```

Or if you wanted to go more functional, you can even do something like:

```js
const func1 = x => y => x + y;

const func2 = x => x;

console.log(func2(func1)(1)(4));
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks heaps for detailed run down. Invoking has done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You are already sending functions as parameters. The incoming property is already a function. You don't need to type '()' again.

```
const func1 = (x, y) => {
const result = x + y;
console.log(result);
}

const func2 = x => {
  x;
};

func2(func1(1, 4));
```