# ngrx showing "Typerror: entities.reduce is not a function" error even when `entities` contains data

Tags: angular, ngrx, reduce, angular-ngrx-data

I'm trying to use ngrx entity dataservice for the first time

- https://ngrx.io/guide/data
- https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-dataservice

The API call is being made and I'm recieving the expected data[image: an array of entities is returned]

But when ngrx tries to proccess it it gets an error on the reduce method
[image]

I have checked other similar questions:

- [Map and Reduce JSON Objects with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010342/map-and-reduce-json-objects-with-javascript)
- ["TypeError: x is not a function" even when code works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037280/typeerror-x-is-not-a-function-even-when-code-works)

But have not found what is causing this.

The response contains an `id` and is not undefined, how can I solve this ?

Since the error is happening inside ngrx I'm not sure about what part of my code show you to help me address this.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when te result contains an array of objects and another data, so the data has to be mapped - http://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2434#issuecomment-751560440

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you map your response as Array. This will resolve your issue:

Example :

```
@Injectable()
export class ForReportsDataService extends DefaultDataService<any> {


    constructor(http:HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator, private dataService: DataService) {
        super('forReport', http, httpUrlGenerator);
    }

    getAll(): Observable<any> {
        return from(this.dataService.GET("/api/reports").pipe(     // map here
            map(res => res["items"])                               // map here
        ));
    }

}
```